# What scenarios will cause 'net' command to return errors containing NET HELPMSG 2185, 2188 and 2192?

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

In https://ss64.com/nt/net-service.html, There are 3 errors that looked very similar

```
"The service name is invalid. More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2185"
"Invalid service program name. NET HELPMSG 2188"
"could not find service name. More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2192"
```

The first one (2185) seems to return when the Service name does not exist in the service controller based on my tests but not sure what will cause the other two errors return.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `2185` is `Display Name` and `2188` is `Service Name`, as represented on the General tab of the service properties dialogue. Invalid being it contains an invalid character or the underlying `.exe` in the executable path can't be found.

`2192` implies the service can't be found by its `Service name`.

[image]

**Note**: I can't find a Microsoft article to back this up, but I feel it's a sensible conclusion to draw.

Comment: OK, so maybe I got 2185 and 2188 the wrong way round?

Comment: Actually, on further tests, I discovered `net stop/start/pause/continue NAME` works for both Display and Service names and `2185` also returns when both are invalid. Do you have some idea on how to force `net` to return errors `2192` or `2188`?